# Python and Tkinter root naming

Tags: tkinter, instance

I often see a GUI using root.mainloop() at the end.
Near the top sometimes they put:
    root=tk.TK()
and sometimes they just put:
    root=Tk()

### Do these two statements do something different? (examples below)

```
from Tkinter import *
class App:
  def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.button = Button(frame, 
                         text="QUIT", fg="red",
                         command=frame.quit)
    self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.slogan = Button(frame,
                         text="Hello",
                         command=self.write_slogan)
    self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)
  def write_slogan(self):
    print "Tkinter is easy to use!"

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

```
import Tkinter as tk

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
  counter = 0
  def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="dark green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the import statements.  After `from Tkinter import *`, all of the names from Tkinter are directly incorporated into your namespace; in fact, you can't refer to `Tkinter` itself because that name wasn't imported.  In contrast `import Tkinter as tk` ONLY imports `Tkinter` (under the shorted alias `tk`), and all further references to names from the Tkinter module have to be prefixed with that name.

Comment: Your answer might be a bit better if you mention PEP8, and that wildcard imports (`from Tkinter import *`) should be avoided.